# HTML5 multiplayer game - how to handle a variable interpolation?

Tags: networking, interpolation

To learn about online game development, I did a HTML5 real-time multiplayer game with NodeJS (server-side), like Agar.io/Slither.io.

Server and client **updates 60 times/s**, but server broadcast packets **20 times/s** to save bandwidth.

Thus, client puts the packets in a buffer and renders them 100ms (constant lerpTime) in the past **by interpolating**. No prediction.

I've tested it on a small server and that's pretty smooth most of the time, but when the server does not keep the fixed rate, it **stops** (jittering) till the buffer is filled enough.

My questions are: how Agar.io and most of other smooth io games handle network congestion? Do they broadcast 60 times/s? How do they handle a variable interpolation time? Are just their servers powerful?

I've seen that they have a variable lerpTime (often < 100 ms, sometimes > 200ms) and a very smooth freezing (probably when lerpTime = lerpTimeMax).

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are not doing preditions, or extrapolation so to say?

Comment: Self-prediction (lerpTime = 0) + interpolation of other entities (lerpTime = 100) gave me a too much desynchronised gameplay (for an action game). So I only do some predictions after lerpTime (= 100, i.e. to save bandwidth). I think Agar.io and other games do the same as we never see any server correction.

Comment: They don't use extrapolation as well (when there is high latency, we see the player stop - fast smooth render - stop - ...). In my case, the player speed changes on each input so extrapolation would give a bad result. What I do for each frame is to find a packet 100ms in the past. With high latency, I have stop (no packet found, wait the next ones) - **bad player jump** + smooth render - stop - ...

Comment: I think you are doing it right. I don't think they broadcast 60 times/s. I have tried using extrapolation too but I find that if the players snaps back a little occasionally in a top down MMO game like that the game experience will be worse than without extrapolation.

Comment: Got issues with client-side prediction/extrapolation because of timed physics (as the clock server and the client server are not synchonised). I would be very interested to know how the other "io" games smooth it. To remove jittering, I think I will render **all** the packets and speedup the "late" ones till the "in-time" packets.

Comment: Any success on this issue?